# Locking different classes with same base class

Tags: java

In an application I have different handlers extending from an abstract class like:

```
public abstract class AbstractHandler {
    public void methodA() {
    }

    public void methodB() {
    }
}

public class FooHandler extends AbstractHandler {
}

public class BarHandler extends AbstractHandler {
}
```

Now I have to synchronize instances of Foo-/BarHandler with each other

a first thought was to add a LockingHandler class between:

```
public abstract class LockingHandler extends AbstractHandler {
    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

    public void methodA() {
        synchronized ( LOCK )
        {
            super.methodA();
        }
    }

    public void methodB() {
        synchronized ( LOCK )
        {
            super.methodB();
        }
    }
}
```

and extending Foo-/BarHandler from LockingHandler:

```
public class FooHandler extends LockingHandler {
}

public class BarHandler extends LockingHandler {
}
```

Is that a viable solution or should the LOCK variable go into AbstractHandler (without using an extra LockingHandler class between, i think if other classes uses AbstractHandler too without the need of same locking context) ?

Comment: It's not a viable solution because the lock is `static`. That means that *all* instances will share a single lock and I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: If you want two objects to share the same lock, pass it through the constructors.

Comment: @Kuhar: yes, all instances should lock on same lock object